# how to create shell script to check if two commits are equal

Tags: git, bash, shell

I have a small shell script I'm writing, but I can't get the syntax right. All it does is check if git is up to date by checking commit hashes using rev-parse.

So this:  `(git rev-parse HEAD) == $(git rev-parse @{u})`

should tell me if i need to do a `git pull` or not. If both return the same number, then I know the commit hashes are the same, and I don't need to do anything. But now I'm trying to put this in a shell script, and I have issues. Here is what i have so far:

```
#!/bin/sh
export isNew = (git rev-parse HEAD) -eq $(git rev-parse @{u})

if [$isNew -eq 0]; then
echo "its new"
fi
```

But I get the following error :

```
$./myscript.sh
./myscript.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./myscript.sh: line 2: `export isNew = (git rev-parse HEAD) -eq $(git rev-parse @{u})'
```

Comment: missing '$' before `(git rev-parse HEAD)` is your first issue

Comment: You can simplify it as `if [ $(git rev-parse HEAD) == $(git rev-parse @{u}) ]; then`.

Comment: i'd like the results stored in a variable, can you help ?

Comment: `-eq` is an argument to the `test` command. Try `isnew=$(test $(git rev-parse HEAD) -eq $(git rev-parse @{u}))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

# Test for equality
[ $(git rev-parse HEAD) == $(git rev-parse @{u}) ]
# Assign result to a new variable (0 for true)
isNew=$?

# Then you can check isNew
if [ $isNew -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "its new"
fi
```

Square brackets are used to test the condition.
Note that `[ $(git rev-parse HEAD) == $(git rev-parse @{u}) ]` by itself does not output anything but uses a return code to indicate its result.
Therefore, instead of assigning bracketed expression to the variable directly, you need to use `$?`, which contains the return code of the last executed command and assign it to a new variable, if you want to keep it for later use.

For assignment to work, there must be no spaces around `=`, that's why you should write `isNew=$?` and not `isNew = $?`. Additionally, `export` is probably unnecessary in your case, if you only intend to use `isNew` in this script.

One more point, `-eq` tests for numerical equality. To test whether two strings are equal, you probably want `==`.

---

**EDIT**

However, as for your intention to use this script to check whether you need to perform a pull, simply comparing `HEAD` to `@{u}` is not enough, since `@{u}` refers to the tip of your upstream branch, kept locally since the last time you did a `git fetch` and remote branch tip may well have changed since then, but you wouldn't know it just by checking `@{u}`.

Your script will not detect whether someone has pushed to the remote branch, unless you do a fetch to "refresh" your repository beforehand.

With this in mind, it might be better to do something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Fetch the remote branch, tracked by your current local branch.
# This will set FETCH_HEAD to the latest commit in remote branch
# without affecting your working copy.
git fetch
# Test for equality between HEAD and FETCH_HEAD
[ $(git rev-parse HEAD) == $(git rev-parse FETCH_HEAD) ]
# Assign result to a new variable (0 for true)
isNew=$?

# Then you can check isNew
if [ $isNew -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "its new"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have addressed some of this; I'll first add something I like to use with shell variables that are later used for boolean tests.

Let's use your setup:

```
if [ $(git rev-parse HEAD) == $(git rev-parse @{u}) ]; then
    upstream_matches_HEAD=true
    # more code here as desired
else
    upstream_matches_HEAD=false
    # more code here if desired, again
fi
# whatever code here
if $upstream_matches_HEAD; then
    # still more code
fi
```

When setting the variable to `true` we end up running `if true; then ...`.  When setting it to false we end up running `if false; then ...`.  I find it reads nicely later as well, especially if you choose good variable names.

#### ahead, behind, or both

I noticed above (per comments) you may be concerned with who's "ahead" and/or "behind" (upstream vs current branch).  Note that after doing `git fetch`, it's possible that you can be ahead, behind, or even *both*.  For instance, suppose that on branch `develop` you've made 3 commits that you have not pushed ... but a co-worker has made 2 commits that she *has* pushed.  You're now "3 ahead, 2 behind" in `git status` terms.

To get these values, use `git rev-list --count` on `HEAD`-vs-`@{u}`:

```
# find out how many un-pushed commits we have,
# i.e., commits that are on HEAD but not on the upstream
ahead=$(git rev-list --count @{u}..HEAD)

# same for un-merged un-rebased-onto commits: what is
# on the upstream that we don't have?
behind=$(git rev-list --count HEAD..@{u})
```

(You can omit the word `HEAD` from these, although I think it reads a bit better to keep it.)

Answer (score 0):

Were you going for something like this?

```
if [ $(git rev-parse HEAD) == $(git rev-parse @{u}) ] ; then
    echo "It's different"
fi
```

Linux:
There's no need for 'export' there.
You can't use '-eq' alone and save its result.
Note the space after '[' and the space before ']', they're necessary.

Git:

The sums not matching doesn't imply which one's ahead.

Comment: can you help me to put the result in a variable so i can use it elsewhere ? so i want the predicate in a variable called isNew

Comment: oh i thought it meant theat one was ahead ?  thanks for saving me some errors.  Any idea what i can use to check if i need to do a git pull or not ? I need to check in a shell script if my repo needs to do a pull or not.

Comment: You should start with `git fetch` because that will refresh your repository, but won't change your working copy. Pull is like a fetch (get the changes) + checkout (apply the changes). After `git fetch`, `git status` will tell you whether you're ahead, behind, or neither.